# sonarqube error : not authorized to run analysis

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-web

I am trying to execute sonarqube in my local machine. I am getting the following output error.
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
I have checked various documents but not able to get a resolution.

I am executing the following:

```
sonar-scanner.bat -D"sonar.projectKey=test-key" -D"sonar.sources=." -D"sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000" -D"sonar.login=<token>"
```

Getting the following output

```
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=129ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=3890ms
INFO: Load analysis cache
INFO: Load analysis cache (404) | time=16ms
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=16ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: 320 files indexed
INFO: 223 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for css: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for json: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for terraform: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for ts: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for yaml: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module test-key
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=69ms
INFO: Sensor Python Sensor [python]
WARN: Your code is analyzed as compatible with python 2 and 3 by default. This will prevent the detection of issues specific to python 2 or python 3. You can get a more precise analysis by setting a python version in your configuration via the parameter "sonar.python.version"
INFO: Starting global symbols computation
INFO: 15 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 15/15 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Starting rules execution
INFO: 15 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 15/15 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor Python Sensor [python] (done) | time=3831ms
INFO: Sensor Cobertura Sensor for Python coverage [python]
INFO: Sensor Cobertura Sensor for Python coverage [python] (done) | time=77ms
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python]
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python] (done) | time=45ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=11ms
INFO: Sensor IaC Terraform Sensor [iac]
INFO: 15 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 15/15 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor IaC Terraform Sensor [iac] (done) | time=553ms
INFO: Sensor IaC CloudFormation Sensor [iac]
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor IaC CloudFormation Sensor [iac] (done) | time=490ms
INFO: Sensor IaC Kubernetes Sensor [iac]
INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 0/0 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor IaC Kubernetes Sensor [iac] (done) | time=163ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript]
ERROR: INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
ERROR: Node.js not found in PATH. PATH value was: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Pandoc\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;F:\sonar-scanner-4.7.0.2747-windows\bin;
org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandException: Node.js not found in PATH. PATH value was: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Pandoc\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\.pyenv\pyenv-win\shims;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\r4vmadmin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;F:\sonar-scanner-4.7.0.2747-windows\bin;
        at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.locateNodeOnWindows(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:270)
        at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.locateNode(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:232)
        at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.retrieveNodeExecutableFromConfig(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:224)
        at org.sonarsource.nodejs.NodeCommandBuilderImpl.build(NodeCommandBuilderImpl.java:142)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.initNodeCommand(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:183)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServer(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:128)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.startServerLazily(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:212)
        at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.AbstractEslintSensor.execute(AbstractEslintSensor.java:66)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:64)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:88)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:61)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:61)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringModuleScanContainer.java:81)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scan(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:396)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:392)
        at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:361)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:135)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)

INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=23150ms
INFO: Sensor TypeScript analysis [javascript]
INFO: Sensor TypeScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript inside YAML analysis [javascript]
INFO: Sensor JavaScript inside YAML analysis [javascript] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor CSS Metrics [javascript]
INFO: Sensor CSS Metrics [javascript] (done) | time=265ms
INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript]
INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [javascript] (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Project Type Information [csharp] (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor C# Analysis Log [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Analysis Log [csharp] (done) | time=48ms
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=611ms
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
INFO: 1 source file to be analyzed
INFO: 1/1 source file has been analyzed
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=539ms
INFO: Sensor Text Sensor [text]
INFO: 224 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 224/224 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor Text Sensor [text] (done) | time=1140ms
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet]
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Project Type Information [vbnet] (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet]
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Analysis Log [vbnet] (done) | time=29ms
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
WARN: Your project contains C# files which cannot be analyzed with the scanner you are using. To analyze C# or VB.NET, you must use the SonarScanner for .NET 5.x or higher, see https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-msbuild.html
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp]
INFO: Sensor Analysis Warnings import [csharp] (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=41ms
INFO: SCM Publisher SCM provider for this project is: git
INFO: SCM Publisher 184 source files to be analyzed
INFO: SCM Publisher 183/184 source files have been analyzed (done) | time=7157ms
WARN: Missing blame information for the following files:
WARN:   * AcousticsDiagnostics_DashBoard/AcousticsDiagnostics.Python/Acoustics_Diag_Python_Azure_Functions/Acoustics_Diag_Python_Test/test_model_scripts.py
WARN: This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
INFO: CPD Executor 6 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 28 files
INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=88ms
INFO: Analysis report generated in 512ms, dir size=1.0 MB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 5443ms, zip size=374.6 kB
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:05.298s
INFO: Final Memory: 27M/114M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
ERROR: You're not authorized to run analysis. Please contact the project administrator.
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: You are using wrong token, either that token doesn't have permission to this project, please check the token.

Comment: @AshishKumar the token is generated through sonarqube only. I am running the script locally. The repository on which I am executing the sonarqube is in my local machine.

Comment: It seems NodeJs is not found in your current path.
On windows, press Start -> Environment variables.
Edit "PATH" to add the directory containing the NodeJS "bin" directory. 
This might at least help solve the error message displayed :)